# I was trying to scrape some data from website, but cant understand how the webpages calling functions to get the data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to [scrape](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$SPX/options?view=stacked&expiration=2021-07-26-w) for option data table. The website has a drop-down menu to select the expiration.
I can see that the page is making API calls like [this](https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/options/get?baseSymbol=%24SPX&fields=symbol%2CbaseSymbol%2CstrikePrice%2Cmoneyness%2CbidPrice%2Cmidpoint%2CaskPrice%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2Cvolume%2CopenInterest%2CvolumeOpenInterestRatio%2Cvolatility%2CoptionType%2CdaysToExpiration%2CexpirationDate%2CtradeTime%2CweightedImpliedVolatility%2ChistoricVolatility20d%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType&groupBy=optionType&expirationDate=nearest&meta=field.shortName%2Cexpirations%2Cfield.description&orderBy=strikePrice&orderDir=asc&raw=1)
to fetch data. However, if I use the link to send a request from python i get nothing, why is that ?? How to correct this ?

```
import requests ##### to connect to web for data 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime  as dt

from  pathlib import Path
#from io import BytesIO
#from zipfile import ZipFile 


date=dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")   
#date='09072021'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
x= True

   url="https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/options/get?baseSymbol=%24SPX&fields=symbol%2CbaseSymbol%2CstrikePrice%2Cmoneyness%2CbidPrice%2Cmidpoint%2CaskPrice%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2Cvolume%2CopenInterest%2CvolumeOpenInterestRatio%2Cvolatility%2CoptionType%2CdaysToExpiration%2CexpirationDate%2CtradeTime%2CweightedImpliedVolatility%2ChistoricVolatility20d%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType&groupBy=optionType&expirationDate=nearest&meta=field.shortName%2Cexpirations%2Cfield.description&orderBy=strikePrice&orderDir=asc&raw=1" 

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}     
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        response = req.get(url).json()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try that code

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote

# create session
session = requests.Session()

# set user agent to avoid cloudflare
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36'

# create url
url = 'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/options/get'

# create params for start page
params = {
    'view': 'stacked',
    'expiration': '2021-07-26-w'
}

# load first page
session.get(
    'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$SPX/options', params=params
)

# create params for AJAX
params_ajax = {
    'baseSymbol': '$SPX',
    'fields': ','.join(
        [
            'symbol', 'baseSymbol', 'strikePrice', 'moneyness', 'bidPrice',
            'midpoint', 'askPrice', 'lastPrice', 'priceChange',
            'percentChange', 'volume', 'openInterest',
            'volumeOpenInterestRatio', 'volatility', 'optionType',
            'daysToExpiration', 'expirationDate', 'tradeTime',
            'weightedImpliedVolatility', 'historicVolatility20d',
            'symbolCode', 'symbolType'
        ]
    ),
    'groupBy': 'optionType',
    'expirationDate': '2021-07-28',
    'meta': ','.join(['field.shortName', 'expirations', 'field.description']),
    'orderBy': 'strikePrice',
    'orderDir': 'asc',
    'expirationType': 'weekly',
    'raw': 1
}

# change headers
session.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
session.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = unquote(session.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'])

# get result
result = session.get(url, params=params_ajax).json()
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "total": 458,
  "data": {
    "Call": [
      {
        "symbol": "$SPX|20210726|1200.00WC",
        "baseSymbol": "$SPX",
        "strikePrice": "1,200.00",
        "moneyness": "+72.24%",
        "bidPrice": "3,125.50",
        "midpoint": "3,126.95",
        "askPrice": "3,128.40",
        "lastPrice": "0.00",
        "priceChange": "0.00",
        "percentChange": "unch",
        "volume": "0",
        "openInterest": "0",
        "volumeOpenInterestRatio": "0.00",
        "volatility": "438.24%",
        "optionType": "Call",
        "daysToExpiration": "6",
        "expirationDate": "07\/26\/21",
        "tradeTime": "N\/A",
        "weightedImpliedVolatility": "14.66%",
        "historicVolatility20d": "10.79%",
        "symbolType": "Call",
...
```

P.S. if I help you - please mark answer as correct